# Is it possible to output the '&' sign in an xml file?

Tags: php, html, xml, browser, encoding

I have a php which generates an xml file and prints it on screen.

Amongst other variables, it prints an Image link.

The problem is that if this Image link has an '&' character in it, I get an xml error because it isn't encoded properly.

So I solve it by replacing the `&` sign with `&amp;`.

Atleast I thought it was solved, now the link to the image is for example like this:

```
  www.domain.com/phones &amp; equipment/img1.jpg
```

which causes a 404 file not found.

The real path is

```
  www.domain.com/phones & equipment/img1.jpg
```

So how can I solve this then?
I would prefer not to change the folder names, I simply didn't know this when I created the folders.

Thanks

Comment: what about CDATA sections in the XML file? You might want to try that. Look for CDATA and XML for further information.

Comment: where do you get the XML error? Where are you trying to read the xml ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a URL, you might want to [URL encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it instead:

```
www.domain.com/phones%20%26%20equipment/img1.jpg
```

Comment: The function in PHP called "urlencode" replaces space with a plus sign (+), so the url wont work, any ideas? I need to have %20 for space instead of +. Thanks

Comment: @Camran: `+` for space should be just as valid for space as `%20`, but if you don't like it for some reason... there's always `str_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

try to

```
www.domain.com/phones+%26+equipment/img1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You should url encode the link using php `urlencode()` function. The code for '&' is "%26".

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you check IANA RFC regarding URL/URI, you will see that space character is not a valid character and shouldn't be present inside REQUEST URI. Having your URL like `www.domain.com/phones-and-equipment/img1.jpg` would be much beneficial from SEO standpoint as well.

ADDENDUM: For example, check page 2, section "Unsafe" of [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) and see why non-printable and non-US-ASCII characters are not safe.

Answer (score 0):

use `html_entity_decode` to convert `&amp;` back into an &

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

The correct representation of the ampersand in an XML file is `&amp;`. If that isn't working, the problem is with the code that is reading the XML file and deferencing the URI.